# Differences in XAP-File - but there are none?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a very strange problem. Maybe some can give me some more ideas...

I have a hosted (IIS) SL4-App. In the clientbin there is one xap-file. If I took the installation from our buildserver, all works fine, despite one (and only one) datetimepicker delivers an validaton error if I enter a valid date (string could not be determined as datetime). On a datepicker on the same control, with the exact same xaml (despite the binding), there is no problem.

Ok so far. The strange thing is, this problem only occurs, when I use the xap-file from the build server. If I replace the xap with my local one (based on the same sources of course), it works like it should. Of course I compared the contents of the two xap-files, but both were same.

I have no idea what is going on here...

Comment: did you do a diff that took line ending into account?  i.e windows line ending vs. unix line ending

Comment: what about regional settings?  Is perhaps one a US date format and the other not?

Comment: line endings are same. input format of the datepicker is both the same, or what do you mean Mitch?